# Get wrong class prediction in svm when precision and recall is 1.00

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have a training set of 340 image samples. Is it possible, after training a SVM in scikit-learn, that maybe i make a mistake in train_test_split()
because it uses only 84 samples and returns me these measures:

```
Classification report for classifier SVC(C=1000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
  gamma=0.0, kernel=rbf, probability=False, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
  verbose=False):
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          1       0.60      0.64      0.62        14
          2       0.92      1.00      0.96        12
          3       1.00      1.00      1.00        10
          4       0.30      0.33      0.32         9
          5       0.67      0.80      0.73         5
          6       0.78      0.78      0.78         9
          7       0.64      0.69      0.67        13
          8       1.00      0.62      0.76        13

avg / total       0.75      0.73      0.73        85


Confusion matrix:
[[ 9  1  0  0  0  1  3  0]
 [ 0 12  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 4  0  0  3  0  0  2  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  4  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  2  0  7  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  4  0  0  9  0]
 [ 2  0  0  0  2  1  0  8]]
```

Using all 340 samples i get these measures:

```
Classification report for classifier SVC(C=1000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
  gamma=0.0, kernel=rbf, probability=True, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
  verbose=False):
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          1       0.56      0.95      0.71        37
          2       1.00      0.97      0.99        36
          3       1.00      1.00      1.00        21
          4       0.97      0.80      0.88        41
          5       0.83      0.95      0.89        21
          6       0.88      0.88      0.88        48
          7       0.98      0.81      0.89        73
          8       0.97      0.78      0.87        37

avg / total       0.91      0.87      0.88       314


Confusion matrix:
[[35  0  0  0  1  1  0  0]
 [ 1 35  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 21  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 5  0  0 33  0  1  1  1]
 [ 0  0  0  0 20  1  0  0]
 [ 6  0  0  0  0 42  0  0]
 [10  0  0  1  3  0 59  0]
 [ 5  0  0  0  0  3  0 29]]
```

and in both cases i get wrong class prediction with:
    print(clf.predict([fv]))

Class 3 that it has  precison and recall 1.00 value however predict()  returns me for 14 times wrong class over 21 sample! 66% oof times it's wrong!

This is my code:

```
import csv
import string 

import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC


features = list()
path = 'imgsingoleDUPLI/'

reader = csv.reader(open('features.csv', 'r'), delimiter='\t')
listatemp = list()
for row in reader:
    r = row[0]

    if (r != ','):
        numb = float(r)
        listatemp.append(numb)
    else:
        features.append(listatemp)
        listatemp = list()



print(len(features))

target = [        1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,                   
          1,1,1,1,2,2,2,
          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,                  
          2,2,2,2,2,3,3,
          3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
          3,3,3,3,3,3,3,                  
          3,3,3,3,3,4,4,
          4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
          4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
          4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
          4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
          4,4,4,4,4,4,4,                  
          4,4,4,4,5,5,5,
          5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
          5,5,5,5,5,5,5,                  
          5,5,5,5,6,6,6,
          6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
          6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
          6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
          6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
          6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
          6,6,6,6,6,6,6,                  
          6,6,6,7,7,7,7,               
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,                  
          7,7,7,7,7,7,8,
          8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
          8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
          8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
          8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
          8,8,8,8,8,8,8,                  
          8]

X = features
y = target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
        test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

C = 1000.0

#clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=C).fit(X, y)
#y_predicted = clf.predict(X)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=C).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

print "Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n" % (
    clf, metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_predicted))
print "Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(y,_test y_predicted)

# feature vectors taken from class 3 of training set where predict() assing a different class

fv1 = [0.16666666666634455, 8.0779356694631609e-26, 7.6757837200946069e-22, 1.0, 1.0000000000034106]

fv2 = [0.22222222221979693, 0.012345679011806714, 0.0044444444443150974, 0.13333333333333333, 2.999999999956343]

fv3 = [0.22222222221979693, 0.012345679011806714, 0.0044444444443150974, 0.13333333333333333, 2.999999999956343]

fv4 = [0.16666666666662877, 0.0017361111111079532, 1.6133253119051825e-23, 1.0, 1.6666666666660603]

fv5 = [0.24813735017910915, 0.0088802547101916908, 0.0046856535169676481, 0.4666666666666667, 2.224609846181971]

fv6 = [0.16666666666662877, 0.0017361111111079532, 9.1196662533971301e-23, 1.0, 1.6666666666660603]

print(clf.predict([fv1]))
```

my features file:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2VThLMk9VYVh4ZE0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

`train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)` will take out a random 25% of your data to make the test set (in this case 85 samples) and keep the remaining 75% (in your case it should be 255) to make the training set.

The classification report shows that in your test set you only have 10 samples in class 3 so you cannot observe "returns me for 14 times wrong class over 21 samples" for this class (otherwise it means you are not using the test set for evaluation).

Try to change the value of `random_state` to generate different random splits and check whether or not you always get precision and recall of 1.0 for class 3 for different random split. To automate this procedure and compute the mean of the test scores you can perform [cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html) with [ShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html).